# Android targetSdkVersion 23 checkSelfPermission method

Tags: java, android, android-contacts, android-permissions

I am facing checking permission value in Android 6.0 (API 23). Always get 0 value even permission enable or disable from app's settings.

Below is step which I taken.

Contact permission manually disable from device `settings->apps-> My apps-> permission -> Disable contact permission`.

Still In Android 6.0 every time got 0 value when execute below line of code.

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS)
```

Below is my code. which I define in main launcher activity class

```
// Identifier for the permission request
private static final int WRITE_CONTACTS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 9;
........

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
    {
        sharedPreferencesEditor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.ALLOW_ACCESS_PHONEBOOK), true);
        sharedPreferencesEditor.commit();
    }
    else {
        getPermissionToReadUserContacts();
    }
....

}


// Called when the user is performing an action which requires the app to read the
// user's contacts
public void getPermissionToReadUserContacts() {
    // 1) Use the support library version ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(...) to avoid
    // checking the build version since Context.checkSelfPermission(...) is only available
    // in Marshmallow
    // 2) Always check for permission (even if permission has already been granted)
    // since the user can revoke permissions at any time through Settings
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // The permission is NOT already granted.
        // Check if the user has been asked about this permission already and denied
        // it. If so, we want to give more explanation about why the permission is needed.
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS)) {
            // Show our own UI to explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
            // before actually requesting the permission and showing the default UI
        }

        // Fire off an async request to actually get the permission
        // This will show the standard permission request dialog UI
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS},
                WRITE_CONTACTS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
    }
}

// Callback with the request from calling requestPermissions(...)
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String permissions[],
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    // Make sure it's our original READ_CONTACTS request
    if (requestCode == WRITE_CONTACTS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST) {
        if (grantResults.length == 1 &&
                grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Write Contacts permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Write Contacts permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure your Compile SDK is 23 also

Comment: I have created a RuntimePermissionHelper class which works fine for me. Hope it works for you. You can find it here - https://gist.github.com/passiondroid/cd2ad32e7ba26f4e47ae

Comment: I had define in manifest like below.   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />

Comment: And also compile sdk is 23 becuase i am testing in my one of device which has latest android sdk version 23

Comment: What is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you target SDK 23 (Android 6), all of the permissions (in your manifest) are disabled by default, whereas if your targetSDK is 22 (Android 5.1) and your app is running on Android 6, all of the permissions are enabled by default when the user installs the app, and even if the user revokes the permissions later on, `checkSelfPermission` returns incorrect value of `PERMISSION_GRANTED`

It is also available in the documentation of [PermissionChecker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/PermissionChecker.html)

> In the new permission model permissions with protection level dangerous are runtime permissions. For apps targeting M and above the user may not grant such permissions or revoke them at any time. For apps targeting API lower than M these permissions are always granted as such apps do not expect permission revocations and would crash. Therefore, when the user disables a permission for a legacy app in the UI the platform disables the APIs guarded by this permission making them a no-op which is doing nothing or returning an empty result or default error.

Comment: Radu, Thanks for reply on this issue. So what is the solution for this " even if the user revokes the permissions later on, checkSelfPermission returns incorrect value of ". I want proper value if user revokes the permission later on. This is my application criteria. Because from my apps i am updating contact data in device contact book so If user has contact permission revoke the later on after that if user try to update contact from my apps so apps will crash so before that i must need to check if user revoke the permission so apps will not try to update contact from the apps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but I realized that there were locals modules with target version below 23. After removing them, the bug was resolved.